# Date in Sitemap invalid but the date is correct, maybe too old?

Tags: google, sitemap

I have a sitemap where a `lastmod` date is `1969-08-26`, the format is correct: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime , however Google says that it is incorrect.

Is there a min value for a date? I can not find any restrictions regarding this.

Comment: If you can't put in an accurate date, you should probably just omit the `lastmod` field entirely.  It's an optional field and Google has said that they don't usually pay attention to it because so few sites keep it up-to-date properly. See [How important is it to include <lastmod> in a sitemap?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92507/how-important-is-it-to-include-lastmod-in-a-sitemap)

Comment: "the date is correct" - Although `1969-08-26` appears to predate the internet so that would seem unlikely?! (Why do you "have a sitemap where a `lastmod` date is `1969-08-26`"?)

Comment: @MrWhite the old date reflects an article that was written and originally published in 1969 (print) which must be reflected on a website too. We have decided to convert all dates before 1970 to `1970-01-01` which seems to be accepted by Google.